# log4j config for grails 2+ for dailyRollOver not working

Tags: grails, log4j

```
log4j = {
    def pattern = new PatternLayout('%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{2} - %m%n')
    environments{
        development{
            appenders{
                appender new ConsoleAppender(
                        name: 'stdout',
                        layout: pattern
                )
                appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                        name:"file",
                        file:"/home/logs/app.log",
                        layout: pattern,
                        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd")
            }
        }
        production{
            appenders {
                appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                        name:"file",
                        file:"/home/logs/app.log",
                        layout: pattern,
                        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd")

                rollingFile name:"stacktrace",
                        file:"/home/logs/stacktrace.log"

                appender new ConsoleAppender(
                        name: 'stdout',
                        layout: pattern
                )
            }
        }
    }
    root {
        info("file")  
    }
}
```

DailyrollOver not working.According to the documentation ,I think there should be different files ( app.log.{today's_date}) .but only one file (app.log) exists.Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this config in your any environment,

```
   import org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender // import at the top of the file
   production {

    log4j = {
            appenders  {
                file name : 'loggerFile', 
                file :"/YOUR_PATH/loggerFile.log", 
                append: false, 
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%5p] - %m%n')
                appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                        name: 'dailyAppender',
                        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                        fileName: "/YOUR_PATH/loggerFile.log",
                        layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%5p] - %m%n')
            )

          }
          root {
            debug 'dailyAppender'
            error 'stdout'
            info 'dailyAppender'
          } 
    }  
}
```

> Note :
>
> 1.you need to create the logger file at the given location like 
>        `/YOUR_PATH/loggerFile.log` otherwise app will throw the
>   **FileNotFound** exception.
>
> 2. Separate log for date wise file will take 1 or more hour to reflect after app start.

Comment: Still not working, Only a single file is generated (loggerFile.log)

Comment: You need to wait for the date change (try with changing your server machine date, change date to tomorrow and restart app)

Comment: also check your app running environment (dev/prod/test)

Comment: Note : logs are not moved to new file instantly you need to wait for at least 1 hour, after 1 hour or more time there will be a new file with date.

Comment: my log file's log :
22-12-2017 01:01:18,263  INFO 
21-12-2017 22:01:27,414  INFO
both the log with different date is in a single file(loggerFile.log)

Comment: Those will be separated by log4j itself after sometime ( > 1 hr or more), so wait and watch

Comment: okie, Is there any way to  config maxHistory  like in logback?